# MySQL table not updating at all with JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, crud

I'm working on a CRUD project. All of my other functions are working except update. I have included a catch to see if there are any errors in the SQL statement and it doesn't catch anything. When I press save changes, the code is executed but doesn't reflect any changes in my table. I have checked all of the error logs also and nothing is apparent. Any ideas? (I had to remove the details from the fields as they contain identifiable information).

[image]

```js
function edit(rowID) {
            $.ajax({
                   url: 'ajax.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {
                       key: 'getRowData',
                       rowID: rowID
                   }, success: function (response) {
                        $("#editRowID").val(response.rowID);
                        $("#fullName").val(response.fullName);
                        $("#dob").val(response.dob);
                        $("#ethnicity").val(response.ethnicity);
                        $("#gender").val(response.gender);
                        $("#nhsNo").val(response.nhsNo);
                        $("#hospNo").val(response.hospNo);
                        $("#idMarks").val(response.idMarks);
                        $("#address").val(response.address);
                        $("#tableManager").modal('show');
                        $("#manageBtn").attr('value', 'Save Changes').attr('onclick', "manageData('updateRow')");
                   }
               });
        }
```

```js
function manageData(key) {
            var fullName = $("#fullName");
            var dob = $("#dob");
            var ethnicity = $("#ethnicity");
            var gender = $("#gender");
            var nhsNo = $("#nhsNo");
            var hospNo = $("#hospNo");
            var idMarks = $("#idMarks");
            var address = $("#address");
            var editRowID = $("#editRowID");

           if (isNotEmpty(fullName) && isNotEmpty(dob) && isNotEmpty(ethnicity) && isNotEmpty(gender) && isNotEmpty(nhsNo) && isNotEmpty(hospNo) && isNotEmpty(idMarks) && isNotEmpty(address)){
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'ajax.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'text',
                   data: {
                       key: key,
                       fullName: fullName.val(),
                       dob: dob.val(),
                       ethnicity: ethnicity.val(),
                       gender: gender.val(),
                       nhsNo: nhsNo.val(),
                       hospNo: hospNo.val(),
                       idMarks: idMarks.val(),
                       address: address.val(),
                       rowID: editRowID.val()
                   }, success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                   }
               });
           }
        }
```

```
        $fullName = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['fullName']);
        $dob = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
        $ethnicity = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ethnicity']);
        $gender = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
        $nhsNo = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nhsNo']);
        $hospNo = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['hospNo']);
        $idMarks = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['idMarks']);
        $address = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
        $rowID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['rowID']);

        if ($_POST['key'] == 'updateRow') {
         $conn->query("UPDATE suspects SET fullName='$fullName', dob='$dob', ethnicity='$ethnicity', gender='$gender', nhsNo='$nhsNo',      hospNo='$hospNo', idMarks='$idMarks', address='$address' WHERE id= '$rowID'");
            exit('Record for '.$fullName.' updated.');
        }
```

Comment: Write code instead of sending picture...

Comment: Please post your code here as text instead of an image. It will allow us to read your code easier, and copy it into an editor if need be.

Comment: You're only posting rowID and key as values in your ajax call, The rest of the $_POST values would be empty. You'll need to pass in all values or just the form itself.

Comment: 1) Inspect your network traffic, either with the browser's tools or better with **Fiddler**. This way you can check if the request really contains what you believe it contains (it will not).

2) Set up php debugging or at least log to a file and see what comes in $POST, and how your SQL statement looks like at the end

3) Execute the constructed statement directly in PHPMyAdmin, or whatever you are using and see the result

4) Stop constructing SQL statements this way

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the manageData function

Comment: @IanProbets as ZorgoZ suggested check your traffic on the network. Moreover, you are not checking the result of the query() function call nor you are checking the affected_rows value. If you have an error or zero rows updated, you'll never know and you'll return "Record updated" anyway. I suggest you to add a status and a status_message return value to let the UI know how the call ended

Comment: @ZorgoZ I checked the network traffic as suggested. Under the JSON tab, all of the data is present. It doesn't show in the correct order of the table though. Would that cause a problem? My instincts tell me yes. I have tried the query manually though PHPMyAdmin and it works.

Comment: The order does not matter. Echo your query and make sure it works properly. Also, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to verify that it is inserting, and if not, get the error message to find out why. Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of real_escape_string will prevent all quoting issues and also prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks @aynber. I think I have worked out why it isn't inserting. rowID isn't being stored and therefore, the row isn't updating. Is this because I am using real_escape_string?

Comment: No, that shouldn't affect it. Make sure the rowID is being passed in, and that the input is correct in your form.

Comment: @aynber it's definitely being passed in through getRowData when I initially open the edit modal. But when I click Save Changes, I look at the debugger and can see that rowID is empty.